# How to use Jersey with a newer version of jackson

Tags: json, rest, jersey, jackson, jersey-2.0

I am using Jersey (2.23.1) with `jersey-media-json-jackson`. But that is linked against Jackson 2.5.4. But I need to use Jackson 2.6.0 (or a newer version).

How can I do this?

I tried to set it in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-jsonSchema</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then jackson 2.6.0 is used. (I have also tried newer versions.)

But my rest application throws various `NoSuchMethodError` or `ClassNotFoundExceptions`, like:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.cfg.EndpointConfigBase.<init>(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperConfig;)
```

Is there any way to use Jersey 2.23.1 with Jackson 2.6.0 or newer? TIA!

**Update 1:**

Here is a full stack trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.cfg.EndpointConfigBase.<init>(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperConfig;)V
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.cfg.EndpointConfigBase.<init>(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperConfig;)V
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:278)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:509)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.cfg.EndpointConfigBase.<init>(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperConfig;)V
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.xml.XMLEndpointConfig.<init>(XMLEndpointConfig.java:22)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.xml.XMLEndpointConfig.forReading(XMLEndpointConfig.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.xml.JacksonXMLProvider._configForReading(JacksonXMLProvider.java:137)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.xml.JacksonXMLProvider._configForReading(JacksonXMLProvider.java:47)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase._configForReading(ProviderBase.java:467)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:775)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueFactoryProvider$EntityValueFactory.provide(EntityParamValueFactoryProvider.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.provide(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

**Update 2**

Here is how I enable jackson for jersey:

```
    register(JacksonFeature.class);
    register(JacksonXMLProvider.class);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you want to override a version, you need to look at the [pom.xml](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.23.1/media/json-jackson/pom.xml) of the module. You see in the link that there are three Jackson dependencies explicitly declared

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When you want to use a new version, you have a couple options to go about it. You can explicitly declare *all* of them in your pom.xml file with the version you want, or you can *exclude* all the dependencies, and just explicitly declare the main one.

For the option of explicitly declaring, you can just all the three above, specifying the version you want. Explicit declarations take precedence over *transitive* dependencies. So the explicitly declared ones will always be the ones pulled in, rather than the ones pulled in by Jersey.

For the option of excluding, you can exclude them from from the `jersey-media-json-jackson`, and just add the main one the pulls everything else in. In this case `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` pulls the other two in, so you really only need to declare that one

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Either one of these ways should work.

What happens when you don't declare all dependencies when changing version, is that an older version jar can be pulled in transitively, and one of the newer versions tries to use some classes in that older version jar, and you end up with these kind of errors.

Comment: I used eclipse to exclude any jackson dependency, but I still get the above mentioned errors. I assume jackson api is not backwards-compatible.

Comment: It's possible, but I have used a newer version before myself, and it was not a problem

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace you can post?

Comment: I have update my question with a full stack trace. TIA!

Comment: I got it. I excluded everything correctly, but I have not added all required maven dependencies, which I have excluded. I forgot to add: `jackson-jaxrs-base` and `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`. Now I can use jackson 2.7.5 with Jersey 2.23.1. Thank you very much!