# Jersey and Jackson Compatibility

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

I updated `jersey` version to the latest which is 2.25.1 and I am also looking for upgrading `Jackson` library as part of it but I am struggling to know which version of `Jackson` is compatible with `jersey`? Maven Repo shows 2.9.0.pr1 and I am completely unaware of `pr1`. Which version of `jackson` should I use then?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the latest Jackson features, just add the following, and it will pull in all the Jackson dependencies (maybe 2.5 or 2.6 - something like that)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you need the newest Jackson features, then you should exclude Jackson dependencies from the above one, and add your own. This is explained in [How to use Jersey with a newer version of jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38016814/2587435).

The benefit of using the `jersey-media-json-jackson` is that it doesn't require any extra configuration. It works out of the box.

Comment: Awesome and it makes sense. I already have `jersey-media-json-jackson` and it has pulled 2.8 version of `jackson`. I think it's a good approach to exclude the `jackson` dependencies since I have almost the latest version of it. And, I am not using the latest features of Jackson anyways.